# How can I profile my Node app to see where I'm using up memory and CPU resources?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, node.js, linode

My website, [CompassionPit.com](http://www.compassionpit.com), is powered by Node.js.  I have released the source code; it's [hosted at GitHub](https://github.com/zackster/CompassionPit--Node-/).  The app itself is running on a Linode with 768MB of RAM (I recently upgraded the server; it was at 512MB).

Recently I have been getting CPU usage notifications from Linode: we're increasingly often at 90%+ usage.  I called Linode to see what I could do about upgrading my access to CPU resources, but apparently I'm okay for now, since if we max out to 100% then we can spill over into the next 3 cores (Linodes are 4 processor Xen instances).

**How can I profile my Node app to see where I'm using up memory and CPU resources?**  I predict I'll soon need to restructure the application to be run by a multiple server setup, but I intuitively believe that proper profiling will lead to smarter architecture decisions.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: CompassionPit.com appears to be gone, for anyone coming to this post several years later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had reasonable success using https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector for profiling. There's a setup guide at the bottom of the README file.

As of later versions of Node.js, the profiling part of node-inspector no longer functions. I've had reasonable success with `--prof` (http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/V8Profiler) and https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent as mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: I would like to chime in that from the #Node.js channel on Freenode, people have also suggested dtrace (credit: H4ns) and v8-profiler (Glenjamin).

Answer (score 2):

Node inspector can't profile node after version 0.6.x

The following plugin has been updated to work with new version of v8 (node 0.7.x +). It's the only one besides nodetime.com that is still working. It uses the actual webkit debugger:

https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent

It has very clear instructions as well.

Comment: This is not true anymore. Node inspector has been updated in the meantime.

Comment: @LeoKoppelkamm Where are you seeing that Node Inspector supports profiling? The [README still states](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector#known-issues) "Profiler is not implemented yet".

Comment: I was refering to the 0.6.x comment. Node inspector was completely broken for a while, but that has been fixed in the mean time. I'm gonna edit the answer to clear that up.

Answer (score 2):

As of v6.3.0, [you can now run](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27) `node --inspect your_script.js`.

Node will print a URL to the console, which can be opened in Chrome, which will connect you to reveal a fully-functional Web Inspector that you can use to profile the Node process.

Run `node --inspect --debug-brk` to immediately pause execution (which is handy if you need to start a profiling session as soon as your application starts)